# Software to implement an online programming system

Tags: web-apps, ide, compiler

I know of places like [Codingground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm), and I was wondering if a software like they use to render a complete IDE with menus, editor, console output, etc, is available so I can build something similar for my students.

I'm aware that a technology like dockers or paravirtualization will be needed. That's not the problem. I just can't find an open source product that are able to provide an IDE. Coding Ground is not the only site that offers this service. There are more of them (Hackerrank comes to my mind too), so I wonder if they are all based in the same base code.

So my question is: is there any software available (better if open source) that allows me to build an online IDE + compiler for the C programming language (or any other language for there is a compiler in Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud9](http://c9.io) is a really nice IDE and works with many programming languages, including C. The code behind it is open source. If you have a hard time setting it up, [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/) should be coming out with installers for it within the next few months (it won their voting contest).

EDIT: I just noticed that the old open source version is no longer maintained.
The new one may be a little limited, but if you don't find anything, you can wait for Bitnami.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side online IDEs abound. See https://github.com/showcases/text-editors or http://codemirror.net/ or https://www.wikipedia.org/.

You could teach students to fish for themselves by trying a combination of [remote/web-based terminals](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=web+terminal&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and terminal-based editors.